# Limit of $\frac{{(1+1/x)}^{x^2}}{2e^x}$ when $x\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Find the limit with all passages
>   $$\lim_{x \to\infty}\frac{{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}^{x^2}}{2e^x}$$

I try to find and I have $1/2$ but this result is incorrect
The correct result is $\frac{1}{2\cdot {\sqrt{e}}}$.

Comment: How do you know this is the correct result? Is this homework?

Comment: with wolfram and graph

Comment: You did not answer the second question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An allround method is to use the expansion $\log(1+u)=u-\frac12u^2+o(u^2)$ when $u\to0$ and to consider the logarithm of the ratio which interests you, that is, forgetting the factor $2$ in the denominator,
$$
x^2\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)-x=x^2\left(\frac1x-\frac12\frac1{x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)-x=-\frac12+o(1).
$$
This yields
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x^2}}{2\mathrm e^x}=\frac12\exp\left(-\frac12\right)=\frac1{2\sqrt{\mathrm e}}.
$$

Comment: sorry but i could say $\log(1+u)=u-\frac15u^2+o(u^2)$ when u-->0 and it's true.  Why do we use 1/2 ??

Comment: The only $c$ such that $\log(1+u)=u+cu^2+o(u^2)$ is $c=-\frac12$. Would you be confusing $o(\ )$ and $O(\ )$?

Comment: lim_(x->0) (log(1+x))/(x-(x^2)/5) = 1   
  
lim_(x->0) (log(1+x))/(x-(x^2)/2) = 1

Sorry for the writing.

Comment: True, and irrelevant. Please read my post with attention.

Comment: It's true to use 1/2 for the expansion of taylor, but i do not understand why. sorry

Comment: Which step in my proof do you fail to understand? Please be specific.

Comment: why c=-1/2? and can't be another number?

Comment: Because lim_(x->0)(log(1+x)-x)/x^2=-1/2.

Comment: All right!!! Thank you very much!!! I'm happy :-)

Comment: You confused little-oh ("o") with big-oh ("O"). If the original answer had said "$O(u^3)$" it would have been clearer and more accurate.

Comment: @martycohen I guess your comment is addressed to the author of the question. "Clearer": no. "More accurate": sure, one could also request expansions up to the order of $u^{42}$, these would be "more accurate". (Say, "marty", would you have an agenda here?)